# How to display sum of Pass and Fail from status columns in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I would like to fetch table records as displayed in Expected Query Result Image in mySQL

I have given other two tables named as Testcase Table and Scenario Table for your reference.

[image: Expected Query Result]

[image: Tables]

Please help me to get MySQL query to get the result as mentioned in the first image.

Comment: Is the values for scenario_id & scenario_name between scenario & testcase tables are correct? as it is misleading the given result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A basic pivot query can give you the results you want.

```
SELECT
    t.Scenario_ID,
    s.Scenario_Name,
    SUM(CASE WHEN t.STATUS = 'Fail' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS sum_fail,
    SUM(CASE WHEN t.STATUS = 'Pass' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS sum_pass
FROM TestCase t
INNER JOIN Scenario s
    ON t.Scenario_ID = s.Scenario_ID
GROUP BY
    t.Scenario_ID,
    s.Scenario_Name
```

Comment: Hi Tim, Thanks for the reply but by mistake I have upload wrong table. Actually, In test case table, no Scenario_Name columns exists. I wanted to fetch from scenario table by scenario_ID. Table is updated now

Comment: @Neerajkumar Just inlcude a join to bring in the scenario names from the other table.  The basic query remains the same.

Comment: Big thanks, the result is as expected. thanks again for your quick reply.